# Having issues with jQuery find

Tags: jquery, icheck

I currently have a form that attaches a class to a inputs label when an option has been selected. I had it working beautifully prior to using the iCheck plugin. I'm essentially running through a series of parents in order to find the class '.frmLabel' and adding a class of '.frmLabelChecked' to it. It works for my select and text inputs but it's not working for the radio and check buttons.

From what I can see the iCheck plugin add an additional div element for form styling so it seems to be that adding an additional parent() would fix the issue. It's a little messy but this is the best I can do since the widget I'm using is being pulled in dynamically.

Live examples can be found here: http://bvp.dmediastudios.com and the version without icheck (that works) is here http://bvp.dmediastudios.com/v4/

The code is as follows:

```
    $('.frmInput input[type=radio]').click(function () {

    // buy or lease options, have to seperate functions for each option since the html structure is different for each one so a all size fits solution using parent() is not possible (that I know of) - very lame. BETTER DONE THAN PERFECT!

    if ($('.frmInput input[type=radio]').is(':checked')) {

        // parent(1) = #harwidget, parent(2) = #homefinderform, parent(3) .frmRow - find .frmLabel
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.frmLabel').addClass('frmLabelChecked');

    }

});
```

The checkbox code

```
    $('#divBuyType').on('click', 'input:checkbox', function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.frmLabel').toggleClass('frmLabelChecked', this.checked);
});
```

The non-working version can be found here: bvp.dmediastudios.com, the working version (without iCheck) can be found here: bvp.dmediastudios.com/v4/

Here is the block of html that the above function refers to

```
<div id="mywidget3A0A581997704AA41EB19FFEC804E593" style="text-align:left;">
<div style="width:450px;height:520px;" id="widgetOuter">
    <div id="widgetContainer">
        <div class="widgetHeader" style="display: none;">
            <div class="widgetRight">
                <div class="widgetMidd">
                    <div class="widgetTitle">Home Finder</div>
                    <div class="widgetBackBtn" id="hartab3A0A581997704AA41EB19FFEC804E593" style="display:none;">
                        <img src="" onclick="showSearch('3A0A581997704AA41EB19FFEC804E593')" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="titleBar" id="titleBar3A0A581997704AA41EB19FFEC804E593"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="widgetBody">
            <span id="widgetBodyDiv" style="height:438px;" onscroll="fixTip('3A0A581997704AA41EB19FFEC804E593');">
                <div id="harwidget3A0A581997704AA41EB19FFEC804E593" style="padding: 10px; display: block;">
                    <form name="homefinderform" method="get" class="forms" id="homefinderform">
                        <div class="frmRow">
                            <div class="frmLabel">Buy or Lease :</div>
                            <div class="frmInput">
                                <span>
                                    <div class="iradio_minimal-grey checked" style="position: relative;">
                                        <input type="radio" name="For_Sale" value="1" checked="" onclick="showBuyDiv(this)" class="radioButton" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
                                        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins>
                                    </div>Buy</span>
                                <span>-</span>
                                <span>
                                    <div class="iradio_minimal-grey" style="position: relative;">
                                        <input type="radio" name="For_Sale" value="0" onclick="showLeaseDiv(this)" class="radioButton" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
                                        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins>
                                    </div>Lease</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="frmRow">
                            <div class="frmLabel">Property Type</div>
                            <div class="frmInput">
                                <div id="divBuyType">
                                    <span>
                                        <div class="icheckbox_minimal-grey checked" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input name="PROPERTY_CLASS_ID" value="1" type="checkbox" style="width: 20px; position: absolute; opacity: 0;" checked="">
                                            <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins>
                                        </div>Single Family Homes
                                        <div class="br">
                                            <br>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="icheckbox_minimal-grey" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input name="PROPERTY_CLASS_ID" value="2" type="checkbox" style="width: 20px; position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
                                            <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins>
                                        </div>Townhouse/Condo
                                        <div class="br">
                                            <br>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="icheckbox_minimal-grey" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input name="PROPERTY_CLASS_ID" value="6" type="checkbox" style="width: 20px; position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
                                            <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins>
                                        </div>Highrise Condominium
                                        <div class="br">
                                            <br>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="icheckbox_minimal-grey" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input name="PROPERTY_CLASS_ID" value="3" type="checkbox" style="width: 20px; position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
                                            <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins>
                                        </div>Residential Lots &amp; Land
                                        <div class="br">
                                            <br>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="icheckbox_minimal-grey" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input name="PROPERTY_CLASS_ID" value="4" type="checkbox" style="width: 20px; position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
                                            <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins>
                                        </div>Multi-Family
                                        <div class="br">
                                            <br>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="icheckbox_minimal-grey" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input name="PROPERTY_CLASS_ID" value="5" type="checkbox" style="width: 20px; position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
                                            <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins>
                                        </div>Homes and/or Acreage</span>
                                </div>
                                <div id="divLeaseType" style="display:none;">
                                    <span>
                                        <div class="icheckbox_minimal-grey checked" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input name="PROP_TYPE" value="'SGL'" type="checkbox" style="width: 20px; position: absolute; opacity: 0;" checked="">
                                            <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins>
                                        </div>Single Family Homes
                                        <div class="br">
                                            <br>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="icheckbox_minimal-grey" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input name="PROP_TYPE" value="'THC'" type="checkbox" style="width: 20px; position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
                                            <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins>
                                        </div>Townhouse/Condo
                                        <div class="br">
                                            <br>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="icheckbox_minimal-grey" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input name="PROP_TYPE" value="'HIR'" type="checkbox" style="width: 20px; position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
                                            <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins>
                                        </div>Highrise Condominium
                                        <div class="br">
                                            <br>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="icheckbox_minimal-grey" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input name="PROP_TYPE" value="'LOT'" type="checkbox" style="width: 20px; position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
                                            <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins>
                                        </div>Residential Lots &amp; Land
                                        <div class="br">
                                            <br>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="icheckbox_minimal-grey" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input name="PROP_TYPE" value="'MLT'" type="checkbox" style="width: 20px; position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
                                            <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins>
                                        </div>Multi-Family
                                        <div class="br">
                                            <br>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="icheckbox_minimal-grey" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input name="PROP_TYPE" value="'ACR'" type="checkbox" style="width: 20px; position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
                                            <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins>
                                        </div>Homes and/or Acreage
                                        <div class="br">
                                            <br>
                                        </div>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Start Select Fields-->
```

Any help would be appreciated. It might be easier to view the html on the page itself.

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent()` really?? try http://api.jquery.com/closest/.

Comment: We all have to start somewhere, and I just noticed that I can't trigger a simple alert on click. I'll look into 'closest' though, thank you.

Comment: It looks like iCheck replaces the radio button with a different element, so you aren't actually clicking the radio and `$('.frmInput input[type=radio]').click(function () { });` won't work.

Comment: another option to change `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent()` besides `$(this).closest('.frmRow')` is `$(this).parents('.frmRow')`. Parents transverse more than once until find the one you want

Comment: Jason P, I just figured this out. Was about to post to say ignore this question. I'm retarded. I'll post back in a few and answer my own question just in case someone else runs into the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Raphael I'll give that a shot. I'd love to clean it up a bit, it's a mess right now. Growing pains I suppose :). I'm a rookie when it comes to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anyone else uses this plugin and needs to fire off some type of event using a radio or checkbox use this.

```
$('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
  alert(event.type + ' callback');
});
```

Documentation can be found here: https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck